# Writing a Logstash GEM gives an error: undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

Trying to build a gem to use it for Logstash as a filter. I'm using classes and methods from a .jar file.

The following is my Jruby code so far:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "logstash/filters/base"
require "logstash/namespace"
require 'java'
require 'Processing.jar'

java_import 'process.Process'

class LogStash::Filters::Process < LogStash::Filters::Base

  config_name "process"

  StringPath = "/path/to/file/"
  ML = JavaUtilities.get_proxy_class('processing.Processing')
  @ML = ML.new(StringPath)

  public
  def register
  end

  public
  def filter(event)    
     event["result"] = @ML.Process("any string.")
     filter_matched(event)
  end

end
```

However, it gave me the following error:

```
    ←[31mException in filterworker, the pipeline stopped processing new events, plea
se check your filter configuration and restart Logstash. {"exception"=>#<NoMetho
dError: undefined method 'Process' for nil:NilClass>, "backtrace"=>[
"/path/to/logstash-2.0.0/vendor/local_gems
/dda91dc0/logstash-filter-Process-0.5.0/lib/logstash/filters/processing.rb:54:in 'filter'", "/path/to/log
stash-2.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/f
ilters/base.rb:152:in 'multi_filter'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in 'each'"
, "/path/to/logstash-2.0.0/vendor/bundle/j
ruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:149:in 'mult
i_filter'", "(eval):233:in 'filter_func'", "/path/to/logstash-2.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/
lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:219:in 'filterworker'", "path/to/log/logstash-2.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0
-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:154:in 'start_filters'"], :level=>:error}←[0m
NoMethodError: undefined method 'Process' for nil:NilClass
         filter at /path/to/logstash-2.0.0
/vendor/local_gems/dda91dc0/logstash-filter-Process-0.5.0/lib/logstash
/filters/Process.rb:54
   multi_filter at /path/to/logstash-2.0.0
/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/filters/base
.rb:152
           each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
   multi_filter at /path/to/logstash-2.0.0
/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/filters/base
.rb:149
    filter_func at (eval):233
   filterworker at /path/to/logstash-2.0.0
/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:
219
  start_filters at /path/to/logstash-2.0.0
/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:
154
```

I tried the following:

```
  .
  .
  .
  public
  def filter(event)
     StringPath = "/path/to/file/"
     ML = JavaUtilities.get_proxy_class('processing.Processing')
     @ML = ML.new(StringPath)    
     event["result"] = @ML.Process("any string.")
     filter_matched(event)
  end   
end
```

But it gave me the error:

```
SyntaxError: dynamic constant assignment error.
```

I tried this in a normal jruby file and everything worked with me. Using Logstash's `filter` however is what seems to be giving me an issue here.

Comment: Can you link me to the javadoc on processing.Processing? It looks like your problem might be with the way you reference Java constants from Ruby, but I'll need to see the docs and package structure to be too helpful. You shouldn't need to be using `get_proxy_class` though.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Hi, thank you for your reply. Please note that I've tried the jruby file and everything worked for me, my class and methods coming from the .jar file. However, this error showed up after I tried to use the exact same code with `Logstash`'s gem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are struggling with *local* and *instance* variables in Ruby. Please see [this blog post](http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.dk/2010/03/variables.html) for more information.

When you call `event["result"] = ML.Process(event["text"])` ruby tries to find a local variable named `ML` which doesn't exist. Therefore you get `undefined local variable or method ML.Process(event["text"])`. So, messing around with your variables might solve your problem.

`@ML` is an instance variable and is available in all methods calling it using `@ML` or `self.ML`. Please try this:

```
public
def filter(event)
   event["result"] = @ML.Process(event["text"])
   filter_matched(event)
end
```

Things I stumbled upon:

- Where do `MLVectorPath` and `MLStopWordPath` come from?
- What is `StringPath`? It is assigned but never used.
- Do you have a field `text`? Otherwise change `event["text"]` into `event["message"]`.

However, I know neither your Java code nor your logstash configuration so these things may be okay. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: It still did not work, giving me the same error. I've updated my question with the exact error, and never mind the `StringPath` and the rest, that was an error in copying my code. (updated)

Comment: I was able to fix it. This is what I did: I assigned a variable and called it `@final_ML = ML.Process(:message)` outside of `filter`, then called it in `filter` and it worked.. Thank you so much tho!

Comment: I also forgot to mention that in order for it to work, I've included all my initialization in the public `register`. It's there for a reason, obviously.